# About Static variable declaration before main

Tags: c++

Consider the following C++ code:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        static int y;
    public:
        static void setY(int t) { y = t; }
        int getY() {return y;}
};
int MyClass::y = 0;
int main()
{
    MyClass mc, mc1;
    MyClass::setY(10);
    cout << mc.getY() << endl; //prints 10
    mc1.setY(12);
    cout << mc.getY() << endl; //prints12
    return 0;
}
```

Why do we have to declare  `int MyClass::y=0;` before main ? If we comment that out, we will get an error message such as "undefined variable y". Didn't we just define it in the class? Also, why does it have to be global? Why can't we put `int MyClass::y=0;` in the main function?

Comment: no you didnt define it in the class. `static int y;` is a declaration that needs a definition

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Here we are yet again. Another wrong dupe-hammer close from you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What's wrong with the dupe closing?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It is wrong, is the main flaw.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I just trust you on this and vote to reopen. Oh, that was all that was needed. Heh.